# How do I download .csv files through a JavaScript program and then give them to a Python program in a shell script?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell

I currently have a JavaScript file that creates 3 .csv files when I run it. Separately, I have a Python file that is supposed to take those 3 .csv files as input to generate a new .xlsx file, which I will then download.

I want to automate this whole process with a shell script (likely using Node.js). I'm assuming it's a simple solution no more than 4-5 lines, but I've never written a shell script, so I'm not sure how to download files/use them for input if I'd be eventually doing this on a server. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The way your question title is phrased is very, very specific and also inaccurate.  You might consider rephrasing it to something more along the lines of the actual problem you want to solve, instead of how you think you want to solve it.  I think what you *mean* to write is something along the lines of "How do I output data from one script and input it from another?"  When it comes to Python and Node, at the end of the day those are just interpreters for different languages which, from each other's perspectives, are just other programs on your system.

Comment: In other words, the fact that two aspects of your task happen to be implemented as a JavaScript script on one hand, and a Python script on the other hand, has little to do with how to script a task involving them.  As for "how to write a shell script" all a shell script is, essentially, is taking whatever commands you would enter in the command line and saving them to a file.  That's more or less about it.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Cygwin?